# Execute php code before going to index.html

Tags: php, html, href

I want to create a link inside a php code to redirect to the index.html page, I am able to achieve that with the following line:

```
echo "<a href='index.html'>Main page</a>";
```

But I want to execute another php code which simply removes the content of a file before going back to the index page.

I can execute my php code as I did to go to the index, I mean:

```
    echo "<a href='clear_config.php'>Clear configuration</a>";
```

But I haven't been able to execute both instructions within a same click (first execute clear_config.php and then go to index.html).

How can I do it?

By using redirection within php code I can get the expected result, but I'm just curious about if it is possible to do it with href tags since clear_config.php is also used in another places where doesn't need to redirect to index.html

Comment: Why don't you take help of JavaScript? Isn't it good idea?

Comment: <a href='clear_config_and_go_to_page.php?index.html'>Clear configuration and go to the main page</a>?

Comment: @Jigar7521 Possibly, but I know almost nothing about web-programming and basically I am writing my code by modifying codes I find on the Internet

Comment: May i can help with JS?

Comment: @KonstantinL Didn't work, it keeps on the php page result.

Comment: @Jigar7521 Sure, if it is a proper way of doing that it will be a good answer which can help me and others.

Comment: I meant redirection, see praveen_programmer answer.

Comment: You can also redirect first it to the clear_config.php and then redirect on index.html from that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
header('Location: index.html');
```

In your clear_config_and_go_to_page.php to redirect to other location.

Comment: Thanks, this works, I also thought about doing the redirection inside the php code, but was curious if it was possible to do it with href tags. If finally there is not another way I will do it like that.

Comment: It is not possilbe with same link.If still you want to do that, We have to hit ajax call on onClick method.